# Need Angular Directive that allow only number with maxlength of 2 before decimal and 2 after decimal

Tags: angularjs

I Need Angularjs Directive that allow only number with below restriction:
Exa : input box only accept value less than 99.99

input box can not accept morethan 2 number before decimal point and can not acccept 2 number after decimal points

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

### Use [`ngPattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

You can use the [`ngPattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) to accomplish that, given that the maximum number you can reach with `dd.dd` is `99.99` so you can use regex to validate that.

This regex will do the job `^\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$`. So that you can use `ngPattern` on your input like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" name="input" ng-pattern="^\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$" />
```

### Implement ngMax

Besides, you can implement the [`ngMax directive`](http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/AG2wf/1/) which works with angular forms and accepts bind values so you can provide it from the model.

```
app.directive('ngMax', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMax, function () {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var maxValidator = function (value) {
                var max = scope.$eval(attr.ngMax) || Infinity;
                if (!isEmpty(value) && value > max) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', true);
                    return value;
                }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
        }
    };
});
```

> Ref.: [jsFiddle implementing `ngMax` and `ngMin` by webvitaly](http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/AG2wf/1/)

Then you can use it like angularjs's regular validation directives:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-max="99.99" />
```

> **Note on Javascript number**, the above directive will fail for number like `99.99000000000001` because of javascript rounding pit falls. Therefore, in spite of `99.99000000000001` being greater than `99.00`, it'll produce a `valid` on the form.

Comment: Good one. I was thinking of changing the user's text, but keeping them from entering it to begin with...

Comment: @TonyBasallo updated my solution with a more solid implemented solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have one that performs those specific rules, but creating one is pretty trivial. And since you said directive, I'm thinking you're talking about AngularJS.

Here's a snippet of a directive that will process user input. Your job is to create the rules and return what you want. You can also do alerts, modals, etc., to let the user know about the error or replace the text completely with the new value (based on your rules).

The *your_rules_are_not_met* variable is what would check to see if you need to make a change. If you don't, then you return the user's text.

If you do make a change, make sure you make a change that will not fail your check the next time (every change will call the method twice - once for the initial check and once with the new value). So if you return text that fails, you will **StackOverflow**

In this example a number between 51 and 75 will return 99.25 instead.

```js
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").directive("controlme", function()
{
  return {
    require:"ngModel",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(text){
      
        var myFloat = text * 1;
        console.log(myFloat);
        var your_rules_are_not_met = (myFloat > 50 && myFloat < 76);
        if (your_rules_are_not_met) {
          var newValue = 99.25;
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
          modelCtrl.$render();
          return newValue;
        }
      
        return myFloat;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">

<h2>Your Number is :{{my_data}}</h2>

<input type="text" ng-model="my_data" controlme />


</body>
```